# Confirm delete in form in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I've got some problem with confirmation of deleting data in Laravel.
Here's code. You can see the icon whick respond for deleting and jquery method which i have added to form in class deleteGroup. It does not work. Window does not appear and form deletes element without asking.

```
<a href="" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('destroy-form-{{$value->id}}').submit();">
 <i class="material-icons delete-icon">delete</i></a>
<form class="deleteGroup" id="destroy-form-{{$value->id}}"

action="{{route('lecture.destroy',['id'=>$value->id])}}"method="POST" style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"></input>
@csrf
</form>
```

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                                    $('.deleteGroup').on('submit', function (e) {
                                     if (!confirm('Do you want to delete this item?')) {
                                                        e.preventDefault();
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            });
</script>
```

LectureController:

```
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $lectures = Lecture::findOrFail($id);
        $lectures->delete();
        Session::flash('success', 'Deleted: ' . $lectures->name . '!');

        return redirect()->route('lecture.index');
    }
```

Can someone help?

Comment: try with $('.deleteGroup').on('submit', (e)=>{alert("submit"); e.preventDefault()}); and see if this function is fired

Comment: if i use this script, it works fine... try adding a id to the form and use $('#formid').on('submit', function (e){}); and change formid with the real id of the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has the cool feature in HTML form. You can simply do this.
Here in this code i have deleted person entity.

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['people.destroy', $person->id], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
  {!! Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">Delete</i>',
 ['type' => 'submit',
 'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
 'onclick' => "return confirm('Are you sure?')"]) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

it will give you the alert section like this.
[image]

Comment: Can i do this without button and with icon as I had it before ?

Comment: Yes. Just u need is to remove the Delete text inside <i>tag

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try without Form.

```js
// confirm to delete
$('.delete').on('click', function() {
  // var question= confirm("Do you really want me delete this?");
  if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {} else {
    return false;
  }
});


// delete fact
function removeFact(fact_id, author_id) {

  if (fact_id == '') {
    alert('No Fact Id');
    return;
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('product.author.fact.delete') }}",
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      fact_id: fact_id,
      author_id: author_id
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#facts-load').html(`@include('models.loader')`);
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data == '') {
        $('#facts-load').html('<p class="alert alert-danger">No Result</p>');
        return;
      }
      $('#facts-load').html(data);
    },
    fail: function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-2">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger w-100 delete" onclick="removeFact('{{ $val->id }}', '{{ $author->id }}')"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remove</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

**HTML**

```
<div onclick="deleteGroup({{$value->id}})">
                            <i class="material-icons delete-icon">delete</i>
                        </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function deleteGroup($id) {
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this group?")) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "/lecture/destroy/" + $id, //Your URL here
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.flag) {
                                alert(data.message);
                            } else {
                                alert(data.message);
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        }
                    });



                }
            }
```

**Controller**

```
public function delete_group($id) {
        $grpDetails = Lecture::find($id);
        if (!empty($grpDetails)) {
            $isDelete = Lecture::find($id)->delete();
            if ($isDelete) {
                return response()->json([
                            'flag' => true,
                            'message' => 'Success'
                                ], 200);
            } else {
                return response()->json([
                            'flag' => false,
                            'message' => 'Something went wrong'
                ]);
            }
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                        'flag' => false,
                        'message' => 'Data Not Found'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

[You can view image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3wCj.png)